# Passing formik values of child component to parent component

Tags: react-native

How can I get formik value of child component to parent component. I have one form where I have three components for eg. Basic details, company details and kyc details so I have created 3 child components and each component is handling formik, now I want that formik value in parent component because based on basic details data I want to show and hide kyc details component , please let me know how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Try using props like this:
Screen 1

```js
render(
 <View>
      <Screen2
        onValueChange={() => {
          this.setState({formProps: formProps});
        }}
      />
      <FormButton
        formProps={this.state.formProps}
        // @ts-ignore
        onPress={formProps.handleSubmit}
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-string
        title={'checkout'}
      />
    </View>
)
```

Screen 2

```js
if (onValueChange) {
 onValueChange(formProps);
}
```